# I get wrong answer for distribution of $y$ everytime

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We have a triangle: $A(0,0)$, $B(3,1)$ and $C(1,2)$.

The joint probability density function is given by:

$$p_{X,Y}(x,y) = k\cdot x \, \text{if (x,y) in triangle, otherwise it is zero}$$
I tried to get the distribution for $Y$. I know that I need to get it's probability density function first.

So for lines between the points I got the following equations:

$$y = \frac{5}{2}-\frac{1}{2}x$$
$$y = \frac{1}{3}x$$
$$y = 2x$$

If I reverse them I don't know in which order to apply them in bounds of the integral to find the density function. I know that there are two densities, one for $y\in (0,1) $ and one for $y \in (1,2)$. But I just can't seem to get it right. Is there a systematical way to do this?

Comment: I believe you may need help about *integration* here, not about probability. However, without seeing your own work it will be very hard to guess what you are getting wrong. Can you perhaps post some of your failed attempts, so that someone can try to see what mistake you have made?

Comment: Can you try editing the title to something more informative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask for a systematic way to find bounds. Sketching helps.

[image]

Now do you see that for $ \displaystyle  y \in (0, 1), $ $x$ is bound between lines $x = \frac y 2$ and $x = 3y$?

Also for $ \displaystyle y \in (1, 2)$, $x$ is bound between $\frac y2$ and $(5 - 2y)$.

Comment: I see, so I would pick the first bound the one that is closer to $y$ axis right ?

Comment: And then sum them together.

Comment: What I mean is $\int_{y/2}^{3y}$ and $\int^{y/2}_{5-2y}$. So I would get: $$\int_0^1\int_{y/2}^{3y}(...)dx dy + \int_1^2\int_{y/2}^{5-2y} (...)dx dy = 1$$

Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes that is correct and $f_{XY} (x, y) = kx$ so we get $k = 3/10$

Comment: can I just ask what are we actually doing here with the first part of integration, are we calculating the surface? Could we also use pythagorean theorem here as an alternative ?

Comment: the region here is the support of the given probability density function or in other words, the function is defined in this region. Of course integrating the probability density over the entire area would sum to $1$. If it was a uniform distribution then you would integrate $k \int 1 \cdot dA = k A = 1$ so you could have found area using trigonometry / geometry. But it is not as $f_{XY} (x, y)$ is a function of $x$.